# Regarding tikz error

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-calc, tikzset, tikz-positioning

main.tex for MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning}
\tikzset{block/.style={draw,thick,text width=2cm,minimum height=1cm,align=center},
    line/.style={-latex}
}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage[boxruled,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}



\input{structure}
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\endgroup


\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter1}
  \input{ch1}
\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{blue}{Bibliography}}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

structure.tex for MWE:

```
 \usepackage[
      backend=biber,[![first page][1]][1]
      style=numeric,
      sorting=nyt,
      sortcites=true,
      autopunct=true,
      autolang=hyphen,
      abbreviate=false,
      backref=true,
    ]{biblatex}
    \defbibheading{bibempty}{}
    \addbibresource{Reference.bib}
    
    %   REMARK ENVIRONMENT
    \newenvironment{remark}{\par\vspace{10pt}\small 
    \begin{list}{}{
    \leftmargin=35pt 
    \rightmargin=25pt}\item\ignorespaces
    \makebox[-2.5pt]{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \node[draw=blue!60,line width=1pt,circle,fill=blue!25,font=\sffamily\bfseries,inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt] at (-15pt,0pt){\textcolor{blue}{R}};\end{tikzpicture}} 
    \advance\baselineskip -1pt}{\end{list}\vskip5pt}


    %   PART HEADINGS
    
    \newcommand{\@mypartnumtocformat}[2]{%
        \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
        \noindent\colorbox{blue!20}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\ecart}{\color{blue!70}\Large\sffamily\bfseries\centering#1}}\hskip\esp\colorbox{blue!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth-\ecart-\esp}{\Large\sffamily\centering#2}}}%
    
    % unnumbered part in the table of contents
    \newcommand{\@myparttocformat}[1]{%
        \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
        \noindent\colorbox{blue!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\centering#1}}}%
    
    \newlength\esp
    \setlength\esp{4pt}
    \newlength\ecart
    \setlength\ecart{1.2cm-\esp}
    \newcommand{\thepartimage}{}%
    \newcommand{\partimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thepartimage}{#1}}%
    \def\@part[#1]#2{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
        \refstepcounter{part}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@mypartnumtocformat{\thepart}{#1}}{\partname~\thepart\ ---\ #1}}
        \else%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@myparttocformat{#1}}{#1}}%
        \fi%
        \startcontents%
        \markboth{}{}%
        {\thispagestyle{empty}%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
            \node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
                \fill[blue!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
    
            \node[anchor=north] at (4cm,-3.25cm){\color{blue!40}\fontsize{220}{100}\sffamily\bfseries\@Roman\c@part};
        \node[anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth-1cm,-\paperheight+1cm){\parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}{
                        \printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}%
                }};
                \node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#2}};
                \end{tikzpicture}};
    
       \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \@endpart}
    \def\@spart#1{%
    \startcontents%
    \phantomsection
    {\thispagestyle{empty}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
        \node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
            \fill[blue!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
            \node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#1}};
            \end{tikzpicture}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{%
        \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
        \noindent\protect\colorbox{blue!40}{\strut\protect\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\protect\centering #1\quad\mbox{}}}}{#1}}%
    \@endpart}
    \def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
    \if@twoside
    \if@openright
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \newpage
    \fi
    \fi
    \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
    \fi}


    %   CHAPTER HEADINGS
    \makeatletter
    \tikzset{
        chaptertitle/.style={
            text = black,
            node font = \huge\sffamily\bfseries ,
            text width = \paperwidth-\Gm@lmargin-10pt ,
            align = left
        }
    }
    
    \newif\ifusechapterimage
    \usechapterimagetrue
    \newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}%
    \newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]{\ifusechapterimage\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}\fi}%
    \newcommand{\autodot}{.}
    
    
    \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
        {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
            \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
         \iftrue
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node at (current page.north west)
            {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
                \draw[anchor=west,chaptertitle] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=blue,fill=white,fill opacity=0.7,inner sep=23pt]{\strut\makebox[44cm]{}};
    
       \draw[anchor=west,chaptertitle] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node {\iftrue\thechapter. \fi#1\strut};
       
                \end{tikzpicture}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \else
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node at (current page.north west)
        {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
            \draw[anchor=south west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=blue,fill=white,fill opacity=0.7,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
            \draw[anchor=south west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
            \end{tikzpicture}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \fi\fi\par\vspace*{270\p@}}}
    
    \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.north west)
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
    
    \draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=blue,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
    \draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
    \end{tikzpicture}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \par\vspace*{270\p@}}
    \makeatother
```

ch1.tex for MWE:

The reference used here is \cite{1.1}.

reference.bib for MWE:

```
@book{1.1,
  title={Securing critical information infrastructure: Global perspectives and practices},
  author={Sharma, Munish},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Institute for Defence Studies and Analyses}
}
```

This generates errors and a pdf which looks as attached.[image: file generated after adding tikz]

Though I have added the tikz related code present under 'CHAPTER HEADINGS' in structure.tex but tikz is used under 'REMARK ENVIRONMENT', and 'PART HEADINGS' also. These I have not added in the MWE structure.tex file.

Comment: Please have a look at [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192)

Comment: Thank You @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: Thank You @Andrey L.

Comment: Requesting help for handling this problem related to tikz.

Comment: @moewe can you help me with this problem?

Comment: Structure file is enhanced. Main file is also enhanced. Error related to \usetikzlibrary and \tikzset also shown. Both the files had to be increased in size so that the error can be reproduced. PART HEADING, CHAPTER HEADING and REMARK ENVIRONMENT all contain tikz in some way.

Comment: Welcome. // Hm, nobody will start debugging your code … Please try to narrow it down by deleting everything, which is irrelevant, distracting, misleading. It may happen, that you find the error and cure yourself this way.

Comment: Sorry, but your code makes no sense to me. As a first step, you need to call `\usepackage{tikz}` *before* calling `\usetikzlibrary`. If there are errors, the PDF output is in no way reliable. Try to fix the errors starting from the first error that shows in the log. There is also a stray `[![first page][1]][1]` in the code of `structure.tex`. Please clean up the code and make sure you use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` properly.

Comment: In your `structure.tex` you define an `if` that you immediately set true: `\newif\ifusechapterimage\usechapterimagetrue`. A few lines later you include an image with `\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi`. Since the user has no possibility to set the `if` to `false` in between, this image is always typeset. But you also have `\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}` a few lines up, so this will return an error that tells that there is no file with an empty name. I would really recommend that you go through the code and check again what it does and why.

Comment: The code also refers to commands defined by the `geometry` package that you never load. So it will break eventually. If you just copied the code from somewhere and you are unsure what it does, I'd recomment that you don't use it. Instead, in this case, it would probably be much better that you make clear what the output of your code should be. It seems that you want to put some frame around chapter titles which can probably be achieved with much less code. Maybe somebody can help you with creating this from scratch.

Comment: @JasperHabicht yes i found that i did not load the geometry package and tikz package is written after calling \usetikzlibrary. The stray  [![first page][1]][1]  is also removed. The chapter headings appear inside the frame now. Thank You. In case of \ifusechapterimage the idea is to put an image atop the first page of each chapter. How can this be achieved using \ifusechapterimage?

Comment: @JasperHabicht  regarding cleaning the code the  'CHAPTER HEADINGS', 'REMARK ENVIRONMENT', and 'PART HEADINGS' are required to be there in the structure file. But I need help regarding how much of them is to be removed.

Comment: A way to find out is commenting out, better more lines, compile (which gives errors, of course), and uncomment step-by-step again, best with some reasonable guesses. If you are unlucky, all lines of code are needed, and if you are lucky, many won't. // For this purpose use an editor which allows marking multiple lines and commenting the out or uncommenting them in one go. Texmaker can do that, for example, and many others will allow, too.